# Google analytics tracking code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce, product

How can I configure Google Analytics for each product in Wordpress and Woocomerce ?

I want Google Analytics for all of my products in store! Can anyone describe how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, can you be a bit more specific. What have you tried? Did you try goggling this before? Did you check how to add wordpress google analytics tags?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

Simple configure your script of google analytic in your header or footer part and put the function

put your tracking code in your header or footer.

make sure that your Google tracking code is perfect it is coming to each page if you are done with that than simply put  the below code in your function.php.

```
  <?php
// WooCommerce Google Analytics Integration
function ia_wc_ga_integration( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); // Load The Ecommerce Tracking Plugin

        // Transaction Details
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id': '<?php echo $order_id;?>',
            'affiliation': '<?php echo get_option( "blogname" );?>',
            'revenue': '<?php echo $order->get_total();?>',
            'shipping': '<?php echo $order->get_total_shipping();?>',
            'tax': '<?php echo $order->get_total_tax();?>',
            'currency': '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency();?>'
        });


    <?php
        //Item Details
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product_cats = get_the_terms( $item["product_id"], 'product_cat' );
                if ($product_cats) {
                    $cat = $product_cats[0];
                } ?>
            ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                'id': '<?php echo $order_id;?>',
                'name': '<?php echo $item['name'];?>',
                'sku': '<?php echo get_post_meta($item["product_id"], '_sku', true);?>',
                'category': '<?php echo $cat->name;?>',
                'price': '<?php echo $item['line_subtotal'];?>',
                'quantity': '<?php echo $item['qty'];?>',
                'currency': '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency();?>'
            });
    <?php
        }  
    } ?>
        ga('ecommerce:send');
        </script>
<?php } ?>
 <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ia_wc_ga_integration' ); ?>
```